# The importance of prime numbers in physical theories

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, physics, mathematical-physics, philosophy

Imagine that a friend asks me about what is the importance of prime numbers in physics. What should I tell him/her?

I know that natural numbers should be important in quantum mechanics because there are some quantized quantities. But are prime numbers useful in any branch of physics? It is obvious that multiplication and division are important in physics but it is about real/rational numbers.

> **Question.** Can you provide idea about what is the importance of prime numbers in physics? I'm interested in theories, not in a specific application from a branch of physics. You can add examples or well your reasoning about why prime numbers aren't important *in theoretical physics*. **I wish you a good day.**

Comment: This may be more in the field of engineering rather than physics, but for the time being prime decomposition is _the_ benchmark for quantum computers.

Comment: Many thanks @Arthur

Comment: A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q="prime+numbers"+physics) turned up: ["The unexpected discovery by Montgomery and Dyson at teatime in the 1970s opened a tantalizing connection between prime numbers and mathematical physics that remains strange and mysterious today."](https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2013/primes-random-matrices).

Comment: @KeithMcClary many thanks.

Comment: Fifty years of experience in physics engineering tells me that there is none.

Comment: Many thanks @HandeBruijn I wanted to asks it, since I've some doubts  about what are prime numbers in mathematics (and science).

Comment: [Examples of prime numbers in nature](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43397/examples-of-prime-numbers-in-nature) (mathoverflow).

Comment: Many thanks @KeithMcClary I am going to read it, now!

Comment: All numbers are prime in Physics. It's true for 1, for 2, for 3, ... 4 is experimental error ..., it's true for 5, etc.. Sorry, couldn't resist the old joke. :)

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts many thanks, to me it seems a funny joke, I hope that my comment does not bother our physicists friends :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Keith's comment (or should I say a clone of it), a Google search on: *prime numbers in physics* yielded me the following results:

- [Link 1](http://seedmagazine.com/content/article/prime_numbers_get_hitched/)
- [Link 2](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/surprising.htm)
- [Link 3](https://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.170601)

and many more.

Also see this [interesting paper by Marek Wolf](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1214).

Comment: Thank you again for providing your answer.

Comment: @user244301 No problem. I hope you gain something useful!!

Comment: More claim that reality, it seems. I'm not impressed.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical physicists are modelling how some things "in nature", by their opinion, are functioning. They seek for laws that govern "natural phenomena" and they try to present them in mathematical form.

In that process they use known mathematical theories if those theories are advanced enough to suit their needs and they sometimes advance those theories by their engagement in the whole process.

From all the branches of mathematics the theory of numbers is, in my opinion, the most non-physical one.

But, of course that sometimes connections with some models of physics and theory of numbers arise and become apparent, because also the theory of numbers is connected to other areas of mathematics.

So , it is expectable to see some parts of the theory of numbers to appear in physics, but at the present time there is not much of them, or at least I do not know aboot much of them.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.